# How to send data from one php file to another with 2 href?

Tags: php

I want to send data to other php file

I can send data with this url code to my second php file.

```
www.test.com/second.php?task=demo&id=55
```

I have a href code like this

```
<a href="first.php?task=first&name=Jack">send</a>
```

How can I send this code `second.php?task=demo&id=55` with `a href href="first.php?task=first&name=Jack"` ?

I want to make something like this

```
<a href="first.php?task=first&name=Jack and second.php?task=demo&id=55">send</a>
```

Comment: Have a look at flashing data on requests It will be more beneficial.  But what your after is Header("Location: your url ");

Comment: Your question is not very clear.

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: maybe send both request to php using ajax ? this question is not very clear,

Comment: How can I do this with ajax? Can you help me. I know this question is not very clear, my bad English.

Answer (score -2):

You want to do something like this.

Structure your anchor like this

```
<a class="sender" href="#" data-task="first" data-name="Jack" 
data-task2="demo" id="55">send</a>
```

then let jquery run like this

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
$(document.body).on('click',".sender", function(e){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var task = $(this).attr("data-task");
    var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
    var task2 = $(this).attr("data-task2");
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajax_url + '[INCLUDE PATH HERE]first.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        data: {"task":task, "name": name },
        success: function (response) {
    [output data if necessary]
        }
    });

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajax_url + '[INCLUDE PATH HERE]second.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        data: {"task":task2, "id": id },
        success: function (response) {
    [output data if necessary]
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: XMLRPC? In a client-side `<a>` tag? What are you on about?